# python regex: extract list elements, each of which matches multiple patterns

Tags: python, regex

I am totally new to python. Suppose I have a list as follows.

```
 somelist =  
['AAAA  1234   SD OXD',
 'AAAB  2342   DF BDD',
 'ERTE  3454   RE DFD',
 'GWED  1234   SD TCD',
 'AAAA  2353   SD MKX',
 'VERD  1234   IO ERT']
```

And I would like to extract elements that match both '1234' at position 7-10 and 'SD' at position 14-15 (just an example, could be any combination of positions, with anything in between). The result would be as follows.

```
['AAAA  1234   SD OXD', 'GWED  1234   SD TCD']
```

What I am doing now is to nest a filter() function inside another.

```
x = filter(lambda x: re.match('1234', x[6:10]), filter(lambda r: re.match('SD', r[13:15]), somelist))
```

This works but looks rather chunky and dumb. Can someone help get a solution that's more elegant and faster? The list could contain millions of elements (from lines in a file).

There are many discussions about searching/matching any of the patterns/regexes (**match A OR B**). This is to **match A AND B**, which must be as common a problem as the **OR** problem. Apparently it's gonna get messy if I want to **match A and B and C and ...** at different locations.

> **Update:**  Thank you all. My original question was probably not clear enough. It's basically an 'element must match ALL of several patterns at
>   given positions' question.
>
> Inspired by **Kcorlidy**'s response particularly, I gave it a few quick
>   shots and these worked (and `.` indeed means `'anything'`, except
>   `\n` according to the manual):
>
> To match '1234' and 'SD' at said positions:
>
> `filter(lambda x: re.search(r'.{6}1234.{3}SD', x), somelist)`
>
> To match 'AAAA' and 'SD' at 0:4 and 13:15, respectively:
>
> `filter(lambda x: re.search(r'.{0}1234.{9}SD', x), somelist)`
>
> The take-home message is the **numbers in the curly parentheses**
>   seem to mean **'distance' (number of characters) from the end of the
>   previous pattern** ('distance' from the beginning, i.e. ^, if it's
>   for the first pattern), not the start position of concerned pattern.
>   That's the whole key point. Simple stuff - that's probably why more
>   are interested in the **match A or B** rather than this **match A and
>   B** problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you used two regex, actually it can finish in one regex

```
import re

somelist = [ 
     'AAAA  1234   SD OXD',
     'AAAB  2342   DF BDD',
     'ERTE  3454   RE DFD',
     'GWED  1234   SD TCD',
     'AAAA  2353   SD MKX',
     'VERD  1234   IO ERT',
     'AAAA 2353   SD MKX',
     'AAAA  2353  SD MKX']

print(list(filter(lambda x : re.search(r".{6}1234\s{3}SD",x) ,somelist)))
# ['AAAA  1234   SD OXD', 'GWED  1234   SD TCD']
```

Comment: yes, one compiled regex - that's exactly what I was looking for. getting close. but rather than `\s`, I'd like to make it general, something like `position 6:10 matches pattern1 + anything + position 13:15 matches pattern2 + position...` (I only care about such specific positions). So my exact question here is how to do the `anything (not just whitespace; dot seems to mean 'anything' but I did not make it work)` and how to combine those positions with the `anything`s.

Comment: ok, these worked: `filter(lambda x: re.search(r'.{6}1234.{3}SD', x), somelist)` for matching '1234' and 'SD' at said positions; and `filter(lambda x: re.search(r'.{0}1234.{9}SD', x), somelist)` for matching 'AAAA' and 'SD' at 0:4 and 13:15 respectively. Basically, I misunderstood **the number in the second curly parentheses**. I thought it meant start position of the second pattern while it seems to actually mean **'distance' (number of characters) from the end of the first pattern**. That's the key point.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you need complex regex? You could also use:

```
[x for x in somelist if x[5:9] == '1234' and x[10:12] == 'SD' ]
# ['AAAA 1234 SD OXD', 'GWED 1234 SD TCD']
```

Comment: this worked fine. why is it bad to use regex? is it slower or just because of readability? the reason I would like to use regex is to be concise and to avoid `for` loops (of course `lambda` also seems essentially a for loop). for example, if I want to match quite a few "keys" for each element, then I have to do a lot of `and if`... for regex, I can just define various of search combinations with re.compile() and use them when needed. but you know better and I'd just take advice from you experienced guys.

Comment: It's not necessarily bad to use regex, but in the specific example you gave in the question, this option seemed much easier to me. I don't know your specific use case, so it may well be that RegEx becomes more readable there. But in your question that did not seem to be the case. If you need `and if` logic, you might also consider writing a function that selects which patterns to look for. But again, it's extremely hard to judge what is the best option, since I don't know the entire case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not sure RegEx is the best solution, but this works if you *do* want that:

```
>>> regex = re.compile('.{6}1234   SD.*')
>>> x=re.findall("\n".join(somelist))
['AAAA  1234   SD OXD', 'GWED  1234   SD TCD']
```

Comment: Suppose the result should be: `['AAAA  1234   SD OXD', 'AAAA  2353   SD MKX']`, how would you combine two parts separated by anything (in this case, `'^AAAA + anything + .{13,15}SD.*'`)? To make it more general, I'd just specify fixed positions for each "matching key" (something like `anything + {position1}pattern1 + anything + {position2}pattern2 + anything + {position3}pattern3 + ...`). I tried `'.{0,4}AAAA.{13,15}SD.*'` and that did not work.

Comment: sorry. my original question was not clear enough. but it's basically an 'each element must match several patterns at respective position' question. that's what I meant by comparing the 'match A and B and ...' as opposed to 'match A or B or ...' in my original question. And that's why I was more interested in using regex...